# Align a form in navbar-header on small screens with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

With the following code, on a "middle screen", the result is OK.

[image]
But on a small screen (smartphones), it is not.

[image]

I wish the input and the submit button (magnifying glass) are aligned on the same line.
How I can do that?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Diko Responsive</a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="index.php" method="get">
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <input id="terme" name="terme" placeholder="Veuillez saisir un terme" class="form-control input-xs" type="search">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I added this CSS file after the advices of @NiklasMH

```
@media (max-width : 768px){
    .form-group input {
        width: calc(70% - 32.5px);
    }

    .form-group button {
        width: 40px;
    }   
}
```

But as you can see, both are still not aligned.

[image]

Comment: Use a media query and change the width of the text box to allow room for the button.

Comment: Thx for your comment but I already tried (http://i68.servimg.com/u/f68/15/03/56/35/sans_t11.png) and still not on the same line, as you can see.

Comment: Are u still looking for the answer.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost there. You only forgot to call `class=input-group`

You no need to add another media queries there.

HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
         <input id="terme" name="terme" placeholder="Veuillez saisir un terme" class="form-control input-xs" type="search">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
</div>
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ndzk568t/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the twitter-bootstrap that good, so this answer is more about what you can do to the CSS.

### Bad practice

Some say it's bad practice, but you could eigther use a table to align them on the same row. Then you also can make the left or right column in fixed width like:

```
td:last-child {
    width: 32px;
}
```

---

### Good practice

Or you can use the calc-value in CSS, which is widly supported now (except in Opera Mini - ref caniuse.com), like:

```
.form-group input {
    width: calc(100% - 44px); /* Minus a little more (4px) than the button-width */
}

.form-group button {
    width: 40px;
}
```

Remember that padding will make the element bigger and force more space, so set box-sizing to border-box (default content-box) to avoid this:

```
.form-group input, .form-group button {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/niklasmh/3gsmy6he/embedded/result/)**

```css
.form-group input, .form-group button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-group input {
  width: calc(100% - 44px);
  max-width: 160px;
}

.form-group button {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input placeholder="text"/>
  <button>btn</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my first message with the result of this, but still not working.

Comment: But the button seems to be wider than what's subtracted, can you test with calc(70% - 41px); ?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the inspected css of the .form-group element and the 2 children? Or reproduce the problem with a JSfiddle? Every layout can be solved with the CSS, we just need to know which rules that are applied already.

Comment: I reproduced the problem and it works like a charm now! The code used is in the edited version of the answer.

Comment: Same result than before for me... Here the Inspector from the last screenshot: formgroup (http://i68.servimg.com/u/f68/15/03/56/35/form-g10.png), input (http://i68.servimg.com/u/f68/15/03/56/35/input10.png) and button (http://i68.servimg.com/u/f68/15/03/56/35/button10.png)

Comment: Bootstrap and all its funny business.. You could go for the table version, no shame in that if the problem is this unsolveable. Tables was made for managing this kind of layout, so you can go for it ;)

Comment: @Fiido Firdauz found a better solution, you should stick with his solution, not my hackish style with Twitter-bootstrap.